# $2\times 5 \times 8 \ldots \times (3n-1)=?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, factorial

Does anybody know if there is a closed form expression using factorials for the above product? I'm not seeing it but I feel like there must be. The recursive relationship corresponding to this expression is just $a_1=2$ and $a_n= (3n-1)a_{n-1}$ but like I said, I'm not seeing it. Any and all insights are welcome.

Comment: What do you mean by closed form? $$\prod_{k=1}^n (3k-1)$$is a perfectly valid representation of the product.

Comment: I don't know, but it's easy enough to prove that this is bounded below by $3^{n-1}(n-1)!$ and above by $3^nn!$. That's probably not helpful, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks very similar to  Pochhammer  symbol used to represent the falling factorial $$(x)_n=x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-n+1)$$ and *when $x$  is a non-negative integer, $(x)_n$ gives the number of $n$ permutations of an $x$ element set, or equivalently the number of injective functions from a set of size $n$ to a set of size $x$* (this is a quote from the corresponding Wikipedia page).

So $$\prod_{k=1}^n (a k-1)=a^n \left(\frac{a-1}{a}\right)_n=a^n\frac{ \Gamma \left(n+1-\frac{1}{a}\right)}{\Gamma \left(1-\frac{1}{a}\right)}$$ In the case of the post $a=3$.

For the recursion given in the post, the formal result is $$u_n=2\ 3^{n-1} \left(\frac{5}{3}\right)_{n-1}$$

Comment: Bravo Claude ! Tu m'as battu, j'étais en train de l'écrire ... +1!

Comment: @OlivierOloa. *Désolé* ! Where are you ? Your profile is not very explicit ! Cheers.

Comment: In France, Paris suburb. Have a good day!

Comment: I'll add that the falling factorial is useful, because the next step might be to compare the result to a binomial expansion or so, which uses a falling factorial.

Answer (score 0):

The multifactorial notation I just found being used online is $$n!^{(b)}=\prod_{k=0}^{\lfloor{\frac{n}{b}\rfloor}} (n-bk)$$ Can someone confirm that this is standard?

Comment: It seems to be a fine notation, but I've never seen it before (even double factorial notation, $n!!$ is not quite standard), and so think it would be worth defining wherever one uses it.

Comment: =) Thanks. What other notation have you seen for this?