# $\prod_{k=1}^n (3k-1)$ in terms of the factorial of natural numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, factorial, gamma-function, products

If $!!$ denotes the double factorial, then
$$(2n-1)!!=\color{blue}{\prod_{k=1}^n (2k-1)=\frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}}$$
for $n\ge 1$. This can be expressed in terms of the gamma function, namely
$$\prod_{k=1}^n (2k-1)=\frac{2^n \Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi}}.$$

It can be observed that
$$\prod_{k=1}^n (3k-1)=\frac{3^n\Gamma \left(n+\frac{2}{3}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)}.$$
But can $\prod_{k=1}^n (3k-1)$ be also expressed in terms of the factorial of natural numbers?

Mayble the triplication formula would be useful:
$$\Gamma (3z)=\frac{3^{3z-1/2}}{2\pi}\Gamma (z)\Gamma \left(z+\frac{1}{3}\right)\Gamma \left(z+\frac{2}{3}\right)$$
(The duplication formula can be used to arrive at $\prod_{k=1}^n (2k-1)=\frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}$ from the gamma representation).

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: Factorial: no. Gamma function: yes.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Could that assertion be proved somehow?

Comment: Someone already asked that: [$2\times 5 \times 8 \ldots \times (3n-1)=?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1273794), but no solution in factorials is provided, only using falling factorial and gamma function. See also [How to write $3\times 7\times 11\times \ldots \times (4n-1)$ as a factorial?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2479353)

Comment: Also these numbers form the [A008544](https://oeis.org/A008544) sequence, you can find some other formulas there.